# Cleaning up the fitness tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retagging

There are currently 65 questions tagged [fitness](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fitness). This tag is vague and general and can encompass a variety of meanings.

Here is a high-level proposal to clean up the [fitness](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fitness) tag:

1. Go through each question tagged as "fitness"
2. Determine what the question is actually asking
3. Retag the question appropriate to the content of the question
4. Request to blacklist the "fitness" tag

Presumably all questions would be related to fitness from the start, and tagging questions with "fitness" would be redundant. Other child sites (like Martial Arts, DIY, and Electronics) have blacklisted tags that match the site name.

Comment: While I agree its weird to have tags that match the site name, what term would you use to indicate questions about your level of fitness?

Comment: @IvoFlipse I think ["physical-activity-level"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_activity_level) is best for that topic. I'm tempted to alias "fitness-level" as such.

Comment: Blacklisting `fitness` on the fitness site shouldn't be an issue. :)

Comment: Agree that fitness is not a good tag. What about nutrition? Also would be pretty broad, but it seems to have a more specific meaning than fitness...

Comment: @Greg I was going to save that for a later meta post after the "fitness" tag cleanup.

Comment: I'm not sure physical-activity-level would be all that useful. That's an insider's term and not something anybody else is likely to use. Getting fit is a common phrase in English; fitness has a colloquial meaning that should be replaced with something equally useful by newbies.

Comment: @Sarge Do you have any other suggestions then? Most of the questions I've gone through so far are using "fitness" in a very general way. There are other tags that suit the questions better once the question is broken down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All done.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have cleaned all questions tagged [fitness](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fitness) today.

The tag really should get blacklisted as soon as possible now, especially because there was not one question where I had a hard time to think of a good alternative better describing the body of the question.

Comment: Thanks for doing that! I'll ping one of the community managers to blacklist the tag for us.

Comment: [tag:fitness] has been blacklisted (marked as intrinsic, since it is). @Matt